# How to dispose WCF services correctly?

Tags: wcf, windows-services, dispose, idisposable

My WCF service is `IDisposable` because it uses a `ReadWriterLockSlim`. When I dispose both of them in the following method:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    lockSlim.Dispose();
}
```

Some of the public methods are still running (or accepting new connections, I don't know), and it fires exceptions because of the attempts of using disposed objects (the lockSlim in this case). It would be nicer if, when stopping a Windows Service hosted WCF Service, the `Dispose` method was called after stopping all running methods and closing it for new connections. But it seems that it must be done manually. There are any shortcuts or examples?

Comment: could you explain your use of ReadWriterLockSlim in a WCF service

Comment: @Mitch I use a `[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]` so I need to create manual locks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no need to dispose LockSlim object. On service stop, call ServiceHost.Close() . all the threads will interrupr its work, all the links will be broken and Garbage colector will take care about the memory. ReadWriterLockSlim is not critical resource. Please let me know if it was helpfull

Comment: It's nice that this question has an answer, but it's a pity that the answer doesn't cover the literal question. These questions show up in Google and StackOverflow searches and it's rare that one person's situation is exactly the same as the person who asked the question; meaning that while the asker's problem was solved, it leaves a useless unanswered question lying around to taunt the next reader who had a legitimate reason for wanting an answer to the question...